# One float number prints okay in C, the other doesn't

Tags: c, printing, floating-point

The result of running the following:

```
struct drinks{
    float alcohol;
    float price;
    char name[1];
};

/*stackoverflow.com/questions/10162152/how-to-work-with-string-fields-in-a-c-struct*/

void main(){

    struct drinks cosmo;
    //The following:
    cosmo.alcohol = 20.67;
    //gives some crazy result when printed ! Says alcohol content is 2345826759803.00000000 (or any random number like that)
    cosmo.price = 10.0;
    char name[] = "Cosmopolitan";
    size_t length = strlen(name);
    realloc(cosmo.name,length);
    strcpy(cosmo.name, name);

    printf("The alcohol content of the %s is %4.2f, and it costs %2.f",cosmo.name, cosmo.alcohol, cosmo.price);
}
```

is exactly what it should be (the name and price of the drink print fine!) except that the alcohol content of the drink prints as a ridiculous number!

P.s. the theme of the code is nonsense, I'm just learning and decided to come up with anything.

EDIT: It worked ! I used the simple fix, thank you ! Can I ask now, and feel free to get technical, why is it that the memory allocation to "name" has any impact on printing the correct float value for the drink's alcohol content ?

Comment: That's not the way you use the 'struct hack' — if you're going to use a technique that was made obsolete by C99 and _flexible array members_ (FAMs), then you must allocate the entire structure plus the array of characters.  You can't reallocate just part of that structure type like that.  (In other structures, under other circumstances (e.g. `char *name;` in the structure), it would be OK; with `char name[1];` like that, it is not OK.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think there ever was a way to correctly use the "struct hack".  Oh and please, lets not invent more C-related TLAs!

Answer (score 2):

you have a field `name` which is a char array of size 1 in your stucture.

You performed a `realloc(cosmo.name,length);` which is undefined behaviour, which can explain that the numbers are then "ridiculous".

Your structure should either define a bigger size for the strings

```
struct drinks{
float alcohol;
float price;
char name[100];};
```

or define a pointer (set it to `NULL` so `realloc` works, or use `malloc`):

```
struct drinks{
float alcohol;
float price;
char *name;};
```

And when you `realloc/malloc`, don't forget string terminator (+1) or use `strdup`

```
cosmo.name = malloc(1+length);
strcpy(cosmo.name, name);
```

or

```
cosmo.name = strdup(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems: The first is that the structures `name` member is an array which will have a size fixed at the time of compilation. You can not reallocate that. Calling `realloc` will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The next problem is that you then copy a to long string into the single-element array thereby writing out of bounds and *again* have undefined behavior.

The obvious and simple solution is to create the array with a larger size to begin with. You can also turn the `name` member into a *pointer* in which case you can allocate memory for it (with `malloc` or `strdup`). If you opt for the second solution and use `malloc`, remember that strings in C have a terminator. So a string like `"hello"` have *six* elements: The five you see and which are counted with `strlen` plus the terminator.

Comment: EDIT: IT worked ! I used the simple fix, thank you ! 
Can I ask now, and feel free to get technical, why is it that the memory allocation to "name" has any impact on printing the correct float value for the drink's alcohol content ?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this in modern C is this:

```
typedef struct {
    float alcohol;
    float price;
    char name[];
} drinks;

...

const char str NAME[] = "Cosmopolitan";
drinks* cosmo = malloc(sizeof(*cosmo) + sizeof(NAME));

cosmo->alcohol = 20.67f;
cosmo->price = 10.0f;
memcpy(cosmo->name, NAME, sizeof(NAME));
// (strcpy is fine too, but is slightly slower)
```

Please note that all the `sizeof` operator calls do take the null terminator in account, since these are C strings.